# How to convert String^ to string ? Visual C++

Tags: c++-cli

How to convert  String^ to string ? I did many attempts, this is an:

```
string y = "";
String ^x = "Hi";
y = y + x;
```

Comment: I am guessing String^ is the Platform::String Class of Windows C++/cx. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, this is String Class

Comment: Is string `std::string`? In any case, which character set/encoding do you want the string to have?

Answer (score 0):

```
//#include <vcclr.h>

System::String * str = S"Hello world\n";
const __wchar_t __pin_ptr * str1 = PtrToStringChars(str);
wprintf(str1);
```

Comment: error C4980: '__pin' : use of this keyword requires /clr:oldSyntax command line option

Comment: try with pin_ptr instead of pin

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is a straightforward way but you could try this.

```
wchar_t* str = x.Data();
std::wstring y(str);
```

Let me know if that works.

**Update:** Explanation: [Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825860.aspx) should give me a pointer to a wchar_t buffer which I could use to create a std::wstring.

Comment: Don't work =( . . .
SEE:


Error 3 error C2228: left of '.Data' must have class/struct/union c:\users\rms\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cadastro\cadastro\Form1.h 259 1 cadastro

Comment: can you try x->Data(). I dont have windows now so I am unable to try but since x is a String^ which is essentially a pointer, I guess we should be using -> instead of '.'.